# Does Spring TransactionTemplate create threads?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, concurrency, transactions

I've got a problem with a corrupted data structure due to concurrent access. I'm trying to rule out possible causes, but I'm not sure how the Spring `TransactionTemplate` works.

There are multiple threads passing independent lists to the constructor of a `CallbackHandler`. This `CallbackHandler` is then passed to the execute method of the `TransactionTemplate`. There are no synchronized blocks anywhere.

The list is accessed in the `CallbackHandler` and from the calling Thread before and after the execute method has finished. As far as I understand calling execute **DOESN'T** start a new `Thread`. Therefor this should be safe.

Every thread creates its own independent list and `CallbackHandler`, only the `TransactionTemplate` is the same for all.

Or does Spring create some new thread at some point?

Comment: can you elaborate on "corrupted data structure due to concurrent access". does one of "those" lists gets corrupted? does it get corrupted on commit? do you have any shared state/statics in your `CallbackHandler`, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view the source code for `TransactionTemplate` [here](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/tags/spring-framework-3.0.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.transaction/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.java).

As you can see, no new threads are created.

Are you sure your thread safety bug doesn't lie in another area of the code? Perhaps it would be helpful to see some examples of what you are doing.

Comment: +1, and in addition to not creating new threads, [TransactionTemplate itself is perfectly thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747478/is-the-spring-transactiontemplate-and-simplejdbctemplate-thread-safe).

Comment: Yeah it was in an other area of the code. But your answer saved me a few hours not searching in the template part :-)