# Thread safety for classes with non-final members with no mutator methods

Tags: java, thread-safety, immutability, final

For the following class, what are the implications of making `mNumSides` final? Is "thread-safety" affected?

```
class Shape {
    private int mNumSides;

    public Shape(int numSides) {
        mNumSides = numSides;
    }

    public int getNumSides() {
        return mNumSides;
    }
}
```

Comment: This codeisn't threadsafe anyway, you know that right ?

Comment: I highly doubt it, but the way you asked the question makes it seem like homework :)

Comment: The class is thread-safe since there is no public setter nor internal modification on `mNumSides`.

Comment: @happybuddha Care to elaborate? It's not clear to me why.

Comment: just set it(`nNumSides`) as `volatile` if you are not going to have read-modify updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. `final` keyword guarantees that all the threads see the same value of `mNumSides` at all the times. More information on `final` and its impact on the Memory Model [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight).

Without using `final` the object might be inconsistently published to other threads, and there is probability (extremely low though) that a thread might see the value of `mNumSides` as `0` rather than `numSides` as passed in constructor.
Making it `volatile` or `static` will also work though.

Comment: As does the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: However, the `final` keyword does not make a class magically thread-safe. It means that the reference pointer of that variable cannot change, it doesn't mean that the contents of the object it points to cannot change. This is *very* important to note in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Great point! However in this case its fine as primitives have no internal data.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison That's correct, primitives store no internal state, and all object-implementations (`String`, `Integer`, `Float`, etc) are immutable by design.

Comment: So to clarify, suppose in one thread I create a global `Shape` object `Shape SHAPE = new Shape(4);`. In the current implementation, there is a risk of other threads calling `SHAPE.getNumSides` and seeing `0` rather than `4`, whereas if I made `mNumSides` final or volatile it would guarantee that other threads see `4`?

Answer (score 0):

Num sides cannot be reassigned if it is declared as [final](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29). There'd be no risk of multiple threads reading different values due to it not being declared as [volatile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

So, declaring the variable as `final` makes the class thread safe.  As of now its **not** thread safe.

Declaring an object final keeps its reference from being reassigned, however if the object had internal data, that data could be reassigned which would **not** be thread-safe.  This is an important point made by Colin on another answer.

In this case the data is a primitive, and so has no internal data.  So here, declaring it final works fine.